# Post to remote file without a form

Tags: php

Without using a form, is it possible to _POST to a different file?

In my case, I want to send a string via _POST, to that file.

Thanks.

---

Update:

Based on a response to my post, I used this:

```
<?php

$ipCreation = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ipCreationCurl = curl_init(); // initiate curl
$url = "accountcreation.php"; // where you want to post data
curl_setopt($ipCreationCurl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ipCreationCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($ipCreationCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ipCreation); // define what you  want to post
curl_setopt($ipCreationCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
$output = curl_exec ($ipCreationCurl); // execute

curl_close ($ipCreationCurl); // close curl handle

var_dump($output); // show output
?>
```

This returns:

"308 Moved Permanently"

---

"nginx"

What's my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can post using curl. Here is a basic example: http://devzone.co.in/post-data-using-curl-in-php-a-simple-example/

```
$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/curl_example.php"; // where you want to post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=value1&var2=value2&var_n=value_n"); // define what you  want to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute

curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle

var_dump($output); // show output
```